# NginX redirect domain.com to domain.com/path when accessing domain.com

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

So basically I had to proxypass the root of a web server @

```
/
```

but the application is hosted at

```
/ui
```

When they don't manually type /ui they are presented with the home page of the server, which is static and not being used. **I want to initially have Nginx
move you to domain.com/ui when you type domain.com then basically just do what it normally does and proxy the application.**

Answer (score 1):

I put this inside my https server block and it redirects the given url, in this example https://subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com/ui and send a permanent flag to remote browser for future reference/speed. *I assume that is why atleast*

```
rewrite ^/$ /ui permanent;
```

or

```
rewrite ^/$ /path permanent;
```

Full Configs:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    subdomain.domain.com;

   return         301 https://$server_name/;
 }

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name subdomain.domain.com;

rewrite     ^/$ /ui permanent;

location / {

    proxy_pass stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: More explanation needed

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - I can't guarantee it will work, but it's worth a shot. Basically it's saying "send requests for the UI folder to this other server". You may need the rewrite in the other answer as well or instead.

```
location /ui {
  proxy_pass (etc);
}
```

Comment: I tried that first trust me, I can't proxypass /ui and the default webroot gets repopulated @reboot so even when I moved /ui to doc root it worked but not persistently, and same with symlinks. I got it tho, thank you!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Is the link you've provided correct? Could you check please?

Comment: I got a [whole question](http://serverfault.com/questions/752323/nginx-proxypass-only-works-via-subdomain-not-domain-com-path?noredirect=1#comment946739_752323) on why I can't proxypass /path, only works via subdomain.domain.com and I also can't proxypass /ui, but thats not a NginX issue.